# Rails render_to_string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render-to-string

I am having difficulty with the rails render_to_string function.  I have created an app using the --api flag, so i think this may be the issue as i have tested in 'full' rails apps and its works just fine.

Essentially i am calling:

```
body_html = render_to_string(template: 'reservations/print')
```

I have also tried

```
body_html = render_to_string('reservations/print')
body_html = render_to_string(partial: 'reservations/print')
body_html = render_to_string(partial: 'reservations/print.html.erb')
```

which should return the html for that template.  The filename is print.html.erb and just has basic data i.e.

```
<p> Hello world. </p>
```

When i output the body_html it is empty.

I referenced this SO question [What is the correct way to render_to_string in wicked pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972189/what-is-the-correct-way-to-render-to-string-in-wicked-pdf) and am also going to use Wicked PDF to generate a pdf file.

Many thanks

Comment: Referencing, the stack overflow question. Did you try passing just `reservations/print` without the template keyword?

Comment: I don't think the `--api` flag is the problem. According to the documentaiton on Rails Api, `AbstractController::Rendering` comes in default and this Module contains the `render_to_string` method.

Comment: Hi Dan, thank you for taking the time to answer.  I have that and a few more.  I will update the question.

Comment: sorry to add another comment, just wanted some fresh eyes if possible

Answer (score 18):

Whilst I do not think this is the best solution doing the following worked.

```
ac = ActionController::Base.new  

html_string = ac.render_to_string(template: 'path_to_file') # e.g. 'posts/show'
```

The Application Controller file in Rails API mode inherits from `ActionController::API`, so I guess the functionality to render is in `ActionController::Base`.

Comment: This should no longer be required (but I haven't tested). See module ActionController::Renderers::ClassMethods: "Both ActionController::Base and ActionController::API include ActionController::Renderers::All, making all renderers available in the controller."

Answer (score 5):

Try the following snippet code:

```
ActionController::Base.new.render_to_string("mailer/your-html-file", locals: { data: your-json-data-that-you-wanna-add-to-your-html-file })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this inside your action:

```
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { render layout: 'your_layout' } # this is for your html responses if you need to respond with html
       format.json { # this block will execute for your json requests

        html = render_to_string action: :index, layout: false, :formats => [:html]
        render json: {data: html}
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that work fine for me:

```
render_to_string partial: 'participant_data.html.erb'
```

The file must be named like this:

```
tickets/_participant_data.html.erb
```