# WickedPDF sending blank pdf as mail attachment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email-attachments, wicked-pdf

```
if params[:invoice_id].presence
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])
  attachments['invoice.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(
      template: 'invoices/service',
      locals: { current_user: }
    )
  )
end
```

I have attached a PDF from [wickedpdf](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf) but after sending the attachment it comes as blank white page.

I am trying to send Attachment in Ruby on Rails with ActionMailer with PDF as an attachment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct way to render\_to\_string in wicked pdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972189/what-is-the-correct-way-to-render-to-string-in-wicked-pdf)

Comment: I dont think it answer my question.

Comment: Since it is the exact same question you must explain *why* it does not answer your question.

Comment: Can you share what versions of Rails and Wicked PDF are you using?

Comment: Latest versions of rails and latest version of wickedpdf

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the example in the [Wicked PDF documentation](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#include-in-an-email-as-an-attachment) it looks like you are missing the `layout` option in the `render_to_string` method.

I suggest to do something like this:

```
if params[:invoice_id].presence
  @invoice = Invoice.find(params[:invoice_id])
  attachments['invoice.pdf'] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
    render_to_string(
      template: 'invoices/service',
      locals: { current_user: },
      # add this line and change the value with the right pdf layout path
      layout: 'layouts/pdf' 
    )
  )
end
```

Comment: its does not fixed it. i have fixed this issue by sending html from controller.